# Markers clustering in android gmaps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to implement marker clustering in android in a repeated way i.e. locations are being fetched from sql server and points are placed on map. But the problem i am facing is that the markers newly plotted or updated are not shown itself, I have to zoom in or out to see the updated markers. I have used

```
mclusterManager.clearItems()
```

but still same thing is happening. Any solution??

Answer (score 1):

You need to force a recluster after adding new items doing

```
mclusterManager.cluster();
```